# Significato di "cacheronzolo"

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Su un giornaletto, anni fa, Rocco ha scoperto che gli indiani spingono i cadaveri sull’acqua, accendono una fiaccola, spargono petali, cantano e i morti, bruciando nel rogo di purificazione, vanno sulla corrente a ricongiungersi al grande spirito. Leggendo, sembrava una cerimonia molto poetica. Ma il fiume di New York è una fogna maleodorante, sulla corrente vanno alla deriva bottiglie, topi morti, **cacheronzoli** e bucce di cocomero.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è un "cacheronzolo"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessun dizionario. Si tratta di italiano regionale?

Comment: Ho visto che questo vocabolo appare anche in [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=URCO-FgPiOAC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&source=bl&ots=-qm2j7Mpy2&sig=ACfU3U2-PViVyLmC-5ZLZI7sjcPagu4ZAQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXgJnv59TgAhWigM4BHVEBCPsQ6AEwAXoECAIQAQ&q=cacheronzoli&f=false) del Settecento. Si parla dei "cacheronzoli" di un cervo, espressione che sembra far riferimento agli escrementi del cervo.

Comment: Appare anche in [questa traduzione del libro *La sofferenza del Belgio* di Hugo Claus fatta da Giancarlo Errico](https://books.google.es/books?id=BsFzAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&dq=cacheronzoli&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjow_Ka7tTgAhVGxxoKHTmqAUAQ6AEIFDAC#v=onepage&q=cacheronzoli&f=false). Il senso qui sembra essere quello di "pallottola di carta".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato di *cacheronzolo* è quello da te indicato nel primo commento, cioè piccolo escremento.

Compare anche in questo passaggio de *[Quer     pasticciaccio brutto de via Merulana](http://brigateperlarte.altervista.org/gadda-carlo-emilio-quer-pasticciaccio-brutto-de-via-merulana/)* di Gadda:

> Tantochè la zozza in parola, tuttavia gargarizzandosi di mille
>   cocococò, e scaracchiandoli infine tutti in una volta al soffitto in
>   un chechechechè riassuntivo, per quanto doppiamente ancorata e dallo
>   spago e dal filo, la si levò a volo fino sul ripiano della credenza:
>   dove, incazzatissima, e rivestita la sua dignità, la depositò, nel
>   vassoio di peltro, un altro bel *cacheronzolo*, ma più piccino del
>   primo: pif! Con che sembrò aver evacuato il disponibile. La paura (dei
>   carabinieri fa novanta).

riferito ad una gallina che deposita un piccolo escremento in un vassoio.

Nel libro *[Brutti, fessi e cattivi - Lessico della maldicenza italiana](http://www.tecalibri.info/C/CASALEGNO-G_brutti.htm)* di Giovanni Casalegno, all'interno della sezione *Il codice dell'offesa* si trova:

> L'individuo spregevole e degno di disprezzo o quanto meno odioso e
>   antipatico è definibile anche merda, pezzo di merda, di merda,
>   merdaccia (di fantozziana memoria), merdone, merdoso, mangiamerda,
>   cagata, faccia di merda, testa di merda, fagotto di merda, palata di
>   merda, palla di merda, sacco di merda, escremento, o nei sinonimi più
>   attenuati cacca, cacherello, ***cacheronzolo***.

dove cacheronzolo viene presentato come sinonimo di escremento, etc.

Comment: È curioso però che non si trovi su nessun dizionario.